# Analyzing a Crash Dump file - Is it possible to peek into Thread's message queue?

Tags: wpf, windows, crash, message-queue, crash-dumps

I have a dump file, where I am getting the ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_QUOTA - "Not enough quota is available to process this command" exception right after > WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.PostMessage
Message coming in is WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED=71.

This message is coming after a window close operation.

- I would like to understand if MessageQueue is at full capacity.
- What is the next message in the queue for processing?
- Was the thread stuck on a specific instruction?

Any suggestions to understand how to unfold some clearity on this will be great.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms820778(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN